# How to choose throughput units for event hub?

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

From the below documentation,
[Click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-faq#throughput-units)

It says that,
Up to 1 MB per second of ingress events (events sent into an event hub), but no more than 1000 ingress events, management operations, or control API calls per second.
If I send JSON like below to the event hub, is the single event or 2 events 
[{'name':'saran'},{'name':'kumar'}]

Comment: `[{'name':'saran'},{'name':'kumar'}]` - This is sending 2 events